# Adding Tag Manager / GA4 event to show as eCommerece data in Reports / Monitization under Google Analytics?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have an issue where data is not showing up in the eCommerce section of Google Analytics.  It shows with some metrics but not where I really want it.

Rather than posting where is there now, I'll post what is sent on completion of a purchase.

Based on the below data.  How do I setup Google Tag Manager (or GA4) to record this in the GA4 eCommerce section of Reports under Monetization?

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', { 'page_title' : 'completed', 'page_path': '/completed' });
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'eec.purchase',
    ecommerce: {
      user_id: '1234567',
      user_email: 'me@myemail.com',
      currencyCode: 'USD',
        purchase: {
          actionField: {
            id: '77777777',
            affiliation: '',
            revenue: 25.00,
            coupon: ''
            },
          products: [{
            id: '22221111',
            name: 'Product ABC',
            category: 'Home Products ',
            variant: '',
            brand: 'Acme, Inc',
            quantity: 1,
            price: 25.00
            }]
        }
      }
    });
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```